# Rich text editor with .txt output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anybody know of a rich text editor with an option to save as .txt?
Thanks

Edit: Clarification: I'm looking for a rich text box for my webiste, not a program for my computer.

Comment: If you don't want formatting, why not just use a <textarea>?

Comment: yes, there is something like notepad++ in windows

Comment: Are you asking for a Javascript in-browser editor or desktop editor?

Comment: If you are talking about HTML editors then You can use TinyMCE
http://www.tinymce.com/index.php

Apart form this you can find a complete list from this url http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_HTML_editors

Comment: What he referred to is a javascript based text editor that can have an **option** to save as *.txt but not limited to *.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any text editor such as TinyMCE or CKEditor and use PHP's [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

Before striping the tags you can issue a few `str_replace()` calls to turn `<br />`s and `</p><p>`s into `\n`s.

If you want to *get funky* you can add a lot of stuff to a script like this such as replacing `<hr />` with `----------------` or similar stuff. But at the basic level the above should be enough.